# Deep Learning with Pytorch - should validation be inside or outside the epoch loop?

Tags: validation, deep-learning, pytorch

I have seen most tutorials/guides having the validation step outside the epoch loop. A guide I follow though has the validation step inside the epoch loop. Which one is right?

I notice that if you have the validation inside the epoch loop you can plot the validation per epoch loss, but you can't have a proper confusion matrix (due to validating the same image dataset all over again) and vice versa. Or I haven't found a proper way yet. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The general way to write training, val loop in PyTorch is:

```py
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for phase, batch in [('train', train_dataloader), ('val', val_dataloader)]:
        if phase == 'train':
            model.train()
            train(model, batch)
        else:
            model.eval()
            val(model, batch)

        # calculate the remaining statistics appropriately
```

A point to note here is that `train_dataloader` and `val_dataloader` are created from the `train_dataset` depending on your crossvalidation strategy (random split, stratified split etc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was puzzled because my confusion matrix was wrong (20 validation images x 30 epochs = 600 total images inside CM). I am not sure how to proceed with creating the confusion matrix, but I think I need to just take the last validation of the last epoch and then create it. So far I was adding to y_true, y_pred for each validation for each epoch. Can you confirm that? Thanks